# Building a form dynamically using Kendo UI

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I have the following requirement:

User enters certain tags in text field (comma separated).

I then need to show a form with text inputs for each of those attributes.

For example: User enters "name, color".

I need to show a form ( in a modal dialog) with

```
name: <text box here>

color: <text box here>
```

How can i build a solution for this using Kendo UI with minimum work ?

Also, I need to retrieve these value back as a JSON

```
{ 
  name: 'John', 
  color: 'Black' 
}
```

My current solution is converting the comma separated value into JSON array, Iterating over those values and manually creating html strings and showing the html in a dialog box.

Since i have to build such views in the future, I need a faster solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use templating with the Kendo javascript framework. This simple example is from the Kendo API documentation at http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/kendo#methods-render

```
<ul></ul>
<script>
var template = kendo.template("<li>#: name #</li>");
var data = [ { name: "John Doe" }, { name: "Jane Doe" }];
var html = kendo.render(template, data);
$("ul").html(html);
</script>
```

Basically define your template and apply your data to it with kendo.render which takes care of iterating over your data to create the html result. The actual html construction is then encapsulated within the template instead of within your javascript.